# How can I decode a json string with 'default' class properties in java?

Tags: java, json, gson

I Tried the following code:

```
public class Member{
  int age;
  String name;
  String eyeColor = blue;


  Member (){
  eyeColor = blue;
  }
}

String newMembers="[{\"age\":\"43\",\"name\":\"Anne\"}]";

Gson gson = new Gson();
Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Member>>() {}.getType();
ArrayList<Member> nMembrs = gson.fromJson(newMembers, listType);
```

A new ArrayList is created containing Member 'Anne' but even with the constructor her eyecolor = null.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: `quantityOfToes` cannot be null (since it is not reassigned from the JSON extraction, it should be 10 still).

Comment: ``int``? How should that be ``null``?

Comment: Are you sure it's null? It's an `int`, how can it be null?

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, this may be relevant [Default Value when deserialized?](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-gson/vcKvgUDxuUk):

> If your class has a default constructor (even an empty one), *your 
>   first pattern (initializing the instances variables where they are 
>   defined instead of in the constructor) should work fine.* If your class 
>   does not have a default constructor, I believe (I could be wrong) that 
>   Gson manually tries to allocate the object, which would skip any 
>   initialization at all. This will actually fail on some platforms (I 
>   have seen posts to that effect about Android allocations failing).
>
> So you *should always make sure Gson-constructed classes have a default 
>   constructor*. It may be that putting the code you showed in the default 
>   constructor worked not because you moved the code around, but because 
>   you had a default constructor at all.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code (Gson 2.2.4, JVM 1.7 on Windows), but in your example `blue` was not defined at all. I defined:

```
 public static final String blue = "BLUE";
```

and so I got this result:

```
 Member [age=43, name=Anne, eyeColor=BLUE]
```

So I suspect that `blue` is defined somewhere but is not initialized since I checked that the default constructor is called. I added also an `int` ivar to `Members` and is setup to 0.

Gson create `Members` using `newInstance` method (roughly calling`new Member()`), if you want pass some values during construction of object, you need to use an [InstanceCreator](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/InstanceCreator.html).